# Chrome extension V3 'The message port closed before a response was received.'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am running into the error 'The message port closed before a response was received.' whilst building a Chrome extension using manifest V3.

In my content script I have:-

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: match}, (data) => {
    // Some error handling
    // DOM manipulation using the data that is received
}
```

Then in the background script I listen for the data being passed from the content script:-

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    sendResponse({ response: parsePhoneNumber(request.data, ['GB', 'AU', 'US']) });
});
```

When I reload the extension everything works as expected.  I am highlighting numbers on a webpage, and the response I am sending back to the content script is an object containing details about the number.

Problem is when I refresh the tab multiple times, eventually I get the 'The message port closed before a response was received.' error.

I had a search and can see others with the same error, but none of the fixes work for me.  There should not be anything async happening here, but I did try returning true from the listener, but the outcome is exactly the same.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you see the error in the content script or in the background script?

Comment: The error comes from the content script.

I have an update though, even when refreshing the page (which I thought would send a message and keep the service worker alive), the service worker dies after 30 seconds.  So the issue here is that the service worker is just inactive after 30 seconds and sending this message then gets this error

Comment: Works for me. When the content script sends a message to the service worker, it becomes active again.

Comment: Sounds like you're hitting the known bug in MV3 when the SW is randomly unregistered. Try uninstalling the extension and install it again.

Comment: Tried that just now thanks, still no joy.  SW inactive after 30 seconds and then refresh of tab but SW stays inactive and error received rather than data, from the message response

Comment: Maybe the bug is somewhere else. Can you show us the entire extension?

Comment: Yes.  I stripped this back to the most basic sendMessage implementation and I can see it working, so the issue is on my end.

So it looks like because I am calling sendMessage from within a forEach loop is where the issue is..  Still investigating

Comment: So yeah it was definitely caused by me calling sendMessage from within forEach loop.  Because I can't send DOM Node to background script I had to rework my code so I pass in array of strings with index (via message), then pass back data to content script, and then do my forEach loop.  Thanks all for your help!